# \parbox with stretchable height

Tags: height, parbox, glue, rubber

I am trying to create a framed `\parbox` that stretches to fill the available space. I have tried

```
\fbox{\parbox[c][0pt plus 1fill][t]{3in}{...Content...}}
```

but the `\parbox` doesn't seem to stretch at all. Is there a way to set the `\parbox` to have a stretchable height? Alternatively, is there a way to save the dimensions of an empty stretchable box and with some trickery, explicitly set the `\parbox` to have the height it should have if it could stretch?

Comment: The remaining space on a page should be given by `{\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal}` (computed between paragraphs).   Inside another box would be more difficult, since the outer box height may not be fixed yet.

Comment: is `\vbox to <dimen>{...}` what you want?

Comment: An example of the kind of material you are using to fill the `\parbox` would be very helpful...

Comment: @sgmoye I am creating an exam with blank boxes to fill in, but I'd also like to be able to fill the boxes with solutions without the height of the boxes changing.

Answer (score 1):

This overlaps a `\parbox` and `\vfill`.  It also uses TikZ and `\tikzmark` to draw a frame around it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newcounter{boxnumber}% for unique tikzmark names

\newcommand{\stretchable}[1]{\par\stepcounter{boxnumber}%
  \strut\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\parbox[t]{3in}{#1}}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \coordinate (top) at (0,\ht\strutbox);
    \coordinate (bottom) at (pic cs:boxnumber.\theboxnumber);
    \draw ($(top)+(2pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(bottom)+(-2pt,-2pt)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}\par
  \vfill\tikzmark{boxnumber.\theboxnumber}\par}
  
\begin{document}

Some text before the box.

\stretchable{\lipsum[1]}

Some text between the boxes.

\stretchable{\lipsum[2]}

Bottom of page.
\end{document}
```

---

Of course, with exam class you can use `\begin{solutionbox}{\stretch{1}} ... \end{solutionbox}`

```
\documentclass{exam}
%\printanswers
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question How high is up?

\begin{solutionbox}{\stretch{1}}
More than you can reach.
\end{solutionbox}

\question Why?

\begin{solutionbox}{\stretch{1}}
Why not?
\end{solutionbox}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your `\stretchable` cannot be inside an `\fbox` and the `\makeemptybox` cannot contain content...

Comment: Ah, back to my old version with \tikzmark.

Comment: It seems like this solution won't work with arguments that have a \par because of \smash. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Interesting!  Fortunately, \smash isn't the only way to overllap.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @John Kormylo's answer, I've gotten some code that lets the width and height be set to any valid `skip`s. I'm not happy with how I compute the size of the box from the `tikzmarks`, and I also feel like I'm recreating parts of `tcolorbox`, but here it is...

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
    \usetikzlibrary{math}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}

% Compute the size of the box with named top and bottom tikzmarker's.
% This cannot be done using Expl3 syntax because it relies on tikz understanding the ":" character.
\NewDocumentCommand{\ComputeBoxDims}{m m}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        % The 0.7\baselineskip is the default height of \strut.
        % This sets the top of the box to be right above the height of the text.
        \coordinate (top) at ($(pic cs:#1)+(0,0.7\baselineskip)$);
        \coordinate (bottom) at (pic cs:#2);
            \draw[very thick, black, fill=blue!10!white] ($(top)$) rectangle ($(bottom)$);
            % Compute the actual width and height of the box.
            \tikzmath{
                coordinate \C;
                \C = (bottom) - (top);
                \Cwidth = abs(\Cx);
                \Cheight = abs(\Cy);
            }
        \global\let\gTmpBoxWidth\Cwidth
        \global\let\gTmpBoxHeight\Cheight
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Make a box of zero size whose content is still shown
% I'm not sure how to do this with only expl3 boxes...
\NewDocumentCommand{\zero_area_box}{+m}{
    \makebox[0pt][l]{
        \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{
            \vbox_top:n {
                #1
            }
        }
    }
}

% A box that takes up no space and will be negatively offset
% by the given width and height
\NewDocumentCommand{\offset_box}{m m +m}{
    \zero_area_box{\vspace{-#2}\hspace{-#1}\zero_area_box{#3}}
}


\skip_new:N \l_fullbox_skip_preferred_width
\skip_new:N \l_fullbox_skip_preferred_height
\dim_new:N \l_fullbox_dim_padding
\dim_new:N \l_fullbox_dim_box_width
\dim_new:N \l_fullbox_dim_box_height
\keys_define:nn { fullbox } {
    width .skip_set:N = \l_fullbox_skip_preferred_width,
    width .initial:n = {0pt plus 1fill},
    height .skip_set:N = \l_fullbox_skip_preferred_height,
    height .initial:n = {0pt plus 1fill},
    padding .skip_set:N = \l_fullbox_dim_padding,
    padding .initial:n = {0.3\baselineskip},
}
\newcounter{fullbox_counter}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fullbox}{o +m}{
    \IfValueTF {#1}{
        \keys_set:nn { fullbox } {#1}
    }{
        \keys_set:nn { fullbox } {}
    }

    \stepcounter{fullbox_counter}
    \tikzmark{fullbox_top.\thefullbox_counter}
    \skip_vertical:N \l_fullbox_skip_preferred_height
    \skip_horizontal:N \l_fullbox_skip_preferred_width
    \tikzmark{fullbox_bottom.\thefullbox_counter}

    % For some reason the tikz picture has a non-zero size,
    % so we stuff it in a size-zero box.
    \zero_area_box{
        \ComputeBoxDims
            {fullbox_top.\thefullbox_counter}
            {fullbox_bottom.\thefullbox_counter}
    }
    \dim_gset:Nn \l_fullbox_dim_box_width {\gTmpBoxWidth pt}
    \dim_gset:Nn \l_fullbox_dim_box_height {\gTmpBoxHeight pt}
    \offset_box
        {
            \dim_eval:n {\l_fullbox_dim_box_width - \l_fullbox_dim_padding}
        }
        {
            \dim_eval:n {\l_fullbox_dim_box_height - \l_fullbox_dim_padding}
        }
        {
            \parbox[l][0pt]{
                \dim_eval:n {\l_fullbox_dim_box_width - 2\l_fullbox_dim_padding}
            }{#2}
        }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question Answer well.
        \begin{parts}
            \part What do you think?

            \fullbox{}
            \part What do you think?

            \fullbox[height=\stretch{2}]{
                \parskip=5pt
                \lipsum[1-2]
            }
            \part Last question...

            \fullbox[height=1in]{}
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: example render]